# Bluetooth keyboard random disconnect and reconnect

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, bluetooth

I'm working with bluetooth keyboad on ubuntu bionic. The problem is that the keyboard at random time disconnect and reconnect itself and I have to wait it to reconnect to allow me to type. I don't know if it is a problem of power management but seems that ubuntu recreate a new devices at every reconnection.

Below my dmesg output:

```
$ dmesg | grep apple
[ 2009.414376] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0001: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 2009.414722] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[ 6310.486954] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0002: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 6310.488353] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0002: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[ 6924.250394] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0006: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 6924.251839] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0006: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[ 8136.584992] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0007: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 8136.587205] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0007: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[ 8748.524965] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0008: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 8748.525626] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0008: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[ 9561.544805] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0009: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 9561.545638] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0009: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[10164.800300] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000A: unknown main item tag 0x0
[10164.801139] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000A: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[15930.182285] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000B: unknown main item tag 0x0
[15930.185265] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000B: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[16130.750918] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000C: unknown main item tag 0x0
[16130.751889] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000C: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[16735.175523] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000D: unknown main item tag 0x0
[16735.177363] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000D: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[17347.231164] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000E: unknown main item tag 0x0
[17347.232098] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000E: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[17951.229308] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000F: unknown main item tag 0x0
[17951.230306] apple 0005:05AC:022C.000F: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[18583.883991] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0010: unknown main item tag 0x0
[18583.884915] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0010: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[19196.003359] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0011: unknown main item tag 0x0
[19196.006753] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0011: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[19805.518069] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0012: unknown main item tag 0x0
[19805.519050] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0012: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
[25655.362846] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0013: unknown main item tag 0x0
[25655.363997] apple 0005:05AC:022C.0013: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on 00:1a:7d:da:71:13
```

Anyone notices that behavior ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue, and after a little searching it appears that this is an unsolved bug in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1385113

However it looks like it has something to do with interference between different BlueTooth devices. The problem is really prominent when I'm using my BT keyboard and my BT headphones together, but if I connect the headphone via cable, the problem disappears. So try that, and hopefully the underlying bug will be fixed soon.